# How to Apply input Mask on a Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I have a textbox on which I apply input masks.

I have downloaded JS library from here [link to js Library with bit documentation](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

What I need to do is that I need format like this

```
any length integer/any length characters/CONSTANT lets say = hello/
current year lets   say = 2012


that is 6666/Edward/thanks SO/2012
```

if var lenght is not possible than atleast one integer or one character and atmost 15 integer or character

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this - http://jsfiddle.net/ZYH9f/

It's one mandatory integer/character and 5 optional others:

```
$("input").mask("*?*****/*?*****/*?*****/9999");
```